# Bypass Fusion Table Layers Caching

Tags: google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3, real-time, google-fusion-tables

I am building a Google Maps application with realtime data.
I am aware of 2 workarounds to refresh a Fusion Table Layer (below).

Is there an API for that- maybe something like the 'reference' that the PlaceResult has?
If not, which workaround is considered to be a better practice?

Workarounds:

Manipulatting the location filter ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996691/why-a-layer-was-incorrectly-reloaded)):

```
fusionTable.setOptions({
 query: {
   select: 'Location',
   from: 'fusion-table-id',
   where: "location not equal to" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString()
 },
 map: _map
});
```

Manipulating the URLs of the tiles ([source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fusion-tables-users-group/wCLHnyoZRYk/uwfOCHicOgEJ)):

```
$("img[src*='fusion-table-id']").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src") + "&" + (new Date()).getTime());
});
```

Thanks,

HW

Comment: The 1st attempt of course is preferable,  because it doesn't require to load the images twice. Also note the 1st comment to [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406879/fusion-table-api-map-not-showing-styles-after-table-update/18408231#18408231) (it's by a google-developer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the 1st option is more expensive as it fetches metadata (XHR) in addition to loading the images.

Comment: But you need this metadata. otherwise, when you only update the image-src and the refreshed image contains a new detail this detail wouldn't be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle) advised:

1. Use the first if you need the metadata (i.e. info window)
2. Use the second if all you need is the geometry.