# How to load Polygons only on part where user zooms in - AngularJS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is the best module to load polygons using the Google Maps API 3 on only parts that the user has zoomed in? For instance, we could set a criteria like IF zoom > 20 THEN load the polygons. But how do we do this using the Google Maps API and how would this selection take place?

**Data set of interest:**
https://npropendata.rdw.nl/parkingdata/v2/ shows list of locations
with the field staticDataUrl as a reference to individual files with Polygons, example: https://npropendata.rdw.nl/parkingdata/v2/static/d8f4e169-b645-40e8-bb53-394d50d46a69

Comment: Is it an option to transfer these data into a  FusionTable?

Comment: If it works, why not... How would you do it? @dr.molle

Comment: I guess your problem is the performance, you must always parse the complete data on clientside and create all polygons. When you use a FusionTable to store the data you may use a FusionTablesLayer to draw the polygons. Benefits: the parsing of the data will be done on serverside and you don't have performance issues with many polygons, because the polygons will be rendered via tiles(and of course only the tiles for the viewport will be loaded)

Comment: Thats a very good tip, I see how it will imprpve the performance. Do you know a good tutorial to start learning about FusionTables?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer should be a good start

Comment: I tried it out, and it looks to me very manual. As I am working with dynamic data, I need the tables to be updated frequently (like every 10s). I don't see how that would work with Fusion Tables as it only supports a manual input for the moment?

Comment: updates are also possible via API, but every 10s will not work in this case, because the tiles will not be updated every 10s(they will be cached for a couple of minutes)

Comment: Thats a big drawback. Which module is responsible for the update? And any insights om how long it is cached. Are there competitors of Fusion Tables?

Comment: The SQL-reference: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference Related to the cache: there is no information about it in the documentation, but Rod McChesney(developer in FusionTables-team) said it's 2 minutes( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406879/fusion-table-api-map-not-showing-styles-after-table-update/18408231#comment27045439_18408231 )